# Can not use Location with newest google play services 7.5.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

**My problem is:**

I'm folowing the new instruction at here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start to implement my own android GCM app.

And, the problems that i have a code part which handle Location tracking, it did work before, but now all the related import are "does not exist". For ex: (error: package com.google.android.gms.location does not exist)

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

**All the things that i have done:**

- Add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1' to top level build file.
- Add compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+' to my app Gradle.

**What i tried**

- Try to use com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0 instead and it work for Location but i'm not sure if GCM will work since i haven't finished it.
- Try to use com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0 instead. It seem sily when the newest is 7.5.0 so 7.5.+ same with ~ 7.5.0. But just tried and failed.

So, did you face it before? and how to solve please?

Comment: replace `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+' ` to `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` and jump to sdk manager update your google library . hope it help

Comment: Thanks for your help, i already did it but the same, still error. I'll put it to "All the things that i have done".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is opening for a long time. Honestly, i tried to give an best answer for that but i can not. I have to switch to use older revision at that time due deadline. And now, back to it and it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you set classpath `'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'` as dependency in top level build
aplied plugin `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`to app build root
added   `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+"` as app build dependency and after  sync you see message `error instal support reposotory` just click on it and install repository from wizard